# CDF of non-atomic singular measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, singular-measures

Suppose $\mu$ is a non-atomic measure on the Borel subsets of $[0, 1]$ such that $\mu$  and
Lebesgue measure are mutually singular. Show that if $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of $\mu$, defined by $F(x) = \mu([0, x])$ for every $x$ in $[0,1]$, then

$$
\limsup_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\infty
$$

except possibly on a set of $\mu$-measure $0$.

Comment: Please clarify what "atomic" means. Also what do you mean by $f(x) = ([0,x])$? Unless you wanted to say something different?  And what is the domain of $f$?

Comment: @user710587 Sorry but "non-atomic" is [quite standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28measure_theory%29#Non-atomic_measures).

Comment: @OP You probably mean $f(x)=\mu([0,x])$, and $\limsup$ (I modified your post accordingly, and retagged). Nice question.

Comment: yes It was an writing mistake. thank you

Comment: What is meant by "except possibly on a set of $\mu$-measure 0"?

Comment: @user710587: It means that the property holds for all $x\in [0,1]\setminus N$, where $\mu(N)=0$.

Comment: I believe that if $\mu \equiv 0$, then it is both singular with respect to Lebesgue measure and trivially non-atomic.  This implies that the question is false, or misstated, or that I'm wrong.